# Enabling websockets support in packaged mosquitto 1.4.7

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

How is websocket support enabled in mosquitto 1.4.7 when it's installed via a package manager (apt-get install mosquitto)? I see there is support for it, but I cannot determine how to enable it (and set the port) in configuration. There is an article that seems to indicate it can be enabled when built from source (https://goochgooch.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/building-mosquitto-1-4/).

Is building from source the only option to enable websocket support?

Comment: Edit your question to include your mosquitto.conf so we can see what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming support is compiled into the build you have then adding the following to the mosquitto.conf should work

```
listener 9001
protocol websockets
```

This will start a websocket listener on port 9001

If the build you have doesn't have websocket support then the following error will be printed to the console:

```
Error: Websockets support not available.
```

Comment: Thanks - I ended up adding these lines:-

    listener 1883 0.0.0.0
    protocol mqtt
    listener 9000 0.0.0.0 
    protocol websockets